# Figure out return of a method that returns empty hash on some condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how to make this work:

```py
def someMethod() -> dict[any, any]:
    if not os.path.exists('some path'):
        return {}

    config = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return config
```

I don't think that's correct. Seeing this error - `Declared return type, "dict[Unknown, Unknown]", is partially unknownPylance`

The idea is to return empty dict if a path doesn't exist (or on some condition) or correct dict with key-value pairs.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could tidy this up a bit with `return {}` instead of a local that you then stomp later anyway.

Comment: makes sense, removed it in question and also in my local code. Thank you! Any ideas on how to get the return type working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997937/how-to-solve-type-is-partially-unknown-warning-from-pyright may be relevant

Comment: As a practical point, `dict[string,int]` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lowercase **any** is a Python built-in function and not a type. Instead, you have to import capital **Any** from the typing module.

```py
from typing import Any
import os

def someMethod() -> dict[Any, Any]:
    if not os.path.exists('some path'):
        return {}

    config = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return config
```

Comment: Since the returned dict is always a `dict[str, int]` that might be better — or even `typing.Mapping[str, int]` if the caller isn’t meant to modify it.